# is there a way to get ip address of email sender using Gmail API

Tags: php, email, geolocation, gmail-api

I'm making an app Using Gmail API.

I want to get ip address of email sender. I've done some research on it. What I'm able to get till now is following.

Each message has headers with information something like below :

```
{
"name": "Received",
"value": "by 10.28.188.5 with SMTP id m5csp628249wmf;        Sat, 17 Oct 2015 21:01:22 -0700 (PDT)"
},
{
"name": "X-Received",
"value": "by 10.182.28.74 with SMTP id z10mr15179312obg.80.1445140882358;        Sat, 17 Oct 2015 21:01:22 -0700 (PDT)"
},
```

Can anyone tell me which one is sender's ip address?

Also will it be accurate to get location from that ip address?

Answer (score 0):

According to me there is no technical way to get the ip-address of someone sending an email via the gmail web interface. Google does not put it into the email headers. And there is no API to query gmail for it.If you really need that IP address for valid reasons, you need to go the legal way.

Comment: what legal way you are talking about?